# how to pass a stl vector to a function which takes a const [] (c++)

Tags: c++, function, vector, constants

i have a 3d stl vector,

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > mdata;
```

i also have a function

```
myfun(const double ya[]);
```

to be more precise, it's a function from the GNU Scientific Library,

```
gsl_spline_init(gsl_spline * spline, const double xa[], const double ya[], size_t size);
```

but this is not related to my problem.

so now i want to pass the 'last' dimension of data to myfun. i've been trying this:

```
for (int s = 0; s < msize; s++) {
    accelerators = new gsl_interp_accel*[msize];
    splines = new gsl_spline*[msize];
    for (int i = 0; i < msize; i++) {
        accelerators[i] = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
        splines[i] = gsl_spline_alloc(gsl_interp_cspline_periodic, msize+1);
        gsl_spline_init(splines[i], &(*mgrid.begin()), &(*mdata[s][i].begin()), msize+1);
    }
}
```

But the compiler (g++, 64bit, Ubuntu), complains:

> In member function
>   ‘`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double,
>   std::allocator<double> >,
>   std::allocator<std::vector<double,
>   std::allocator<double> > > >,
>   std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<double,
>   std::allocator<double> >,
>   std::allocator<std::vector<double,
>   std::allocator<double> > > > > >
>   SimpleAmfCalculator::interp_m(int)`’:
>   Calculator.cpp:100: error: cannot
>   convert ‘`std::vector<double,
>   std::allocator<double> >*`’ to ‘`const
>   double*`’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘`int
>   gsl_spline_init(gsl_spline*, const
>   double*, const double*, size_t)`’ make:
>   *** [Calculator.o] Error 1

Any help is greatly apprecitated!

Comment: You show a declaration for "data", but the variable in the line with the error is "mdata". Are they supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the following seems to work for me:

```
#include <vector>

void fun(const double data[])
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > data3d;
    ....
    fun(&(data3d[0][0].front()));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could pass the address of the first element, for example:

```
#include <vector>

void fun(const double data[])
{

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > data3d;
    ....
    fun(&data3d[0][0][0]);
}
```

---

The elements of `vector` are stored contiguously. So this way is standard as I hope :)

> `23.2.4 Class template vector`
>
> 1 A vector is a kind of
>   sequence that supports random access
>   iterators. In addition, it supports
>   (amortized) constant time insert and
>   erase operations at the end; insert
>   and erase in the middle take linear
>   time. Storage management is handled
>   automatically, though hints can be
>   given to improve efficiency. The
>   `elements of a vector are stored`
>   **contiguously**, meaning that if `v` is a
>   vector where T is some
>   type other than bool, then it obeys
>   the identity:

```
&v[n] == &v[0] + n for
all 0 <= n < v.size().
```

Comment: I think I read once that this used to work in practice or 'de facto' (it assumes that vectors are implemented internally using a contiguous array), and in a newer version of the standard now works in theory or 'de jure' as well.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is portable (vector doesn't provide .data() method like std::string) but this will probably work with most compilers.

Comment: It works as long as there is at least one element. And also note that you may only access `data3d[0][0][0].size()` elements, because the other "sub-arrays" (vectors really) are not allocates right next to it (this seems obvious, but easy to overlook in a hurry, i guess).

Comment: This fails spectacularly if on of the vectors happens to be empty.

Comment: well, this does not work for me -- at least when i do it like this: gsl_spline_init(splines[i], &mgrid[0], &mdata[s][i][0], msize+1)

Comment: This will work for ONE dimension. So assuming [0][0][0] -> x,y,z cordinates. You can access z -> 0 ... n by incrementing the pointer. But you can not get access for any elementas where x != 0 or y != 0.

Answer (score 5):

This cries out for a general solution.

```
template<typename T, typename A>
T* PointerOf(std::vector<T,A> & vec)
{
    return &vec.at(0);
}

template<typename T, typename A>
const T* ConstPointerOf(const std::vector<T,A> & vec)
{
    return &vec.at(0);
}

myfun(ConstPointerOf(mdata[s][i]));
```

*Edit:* I added the template parameter for the vector allocator as suggested in the comments; I also used at() instead of [] so I wouldn't have to check for an empty vector, and I added a second version of the function for a const pointer.

Comment: Doesn't this need to also provide a template for the allocator?

Comment: @GMan, as written, it will accept only vectors that have a `std::allocator<T>` allocator. I guess that's fine for most. But surely adding the allocator would be a bit more generic :)

Comment: You're right, I have never used an allocator in my vectors so it didn't occur to me. Is fixing it just a matter of adding a second template parameter?

Comment: Why's the `const` version named differently? (Oh, and look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339470/how-to-get-the-address-of-the-stdvector-buffer-start-most-elegantly/1339767#1339767)

Comment: I named the const version so you could choose to return a const or non-const pointer. Since T* will implicitly convert to const T*, I probably didn't need to do that. Still need two versions of the function though.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
&(*mdata[s][i].begin());
```

is returning a `std:vector` of type `double`.

Comment: No, it's returning an iterator. You're thinking of front().

Comment: No, front returns a double.  But it does return an iterator.  No function call would return an std::vector of type double.

Comment: "Calculator.cpp:100: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*’ to ‘const double*’ for argument ‘3’ "

Comment: That returns an iterator, which may or may not be compatible with a double* .