# Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I am pre-allocating some memory to my a `vector` data member. Example:

```cpp
class A {
    vector<string> t_Names;
  public:
      A () : t_Names(1000) {}
};
```

At some point in time, if the `t_Names.size()` equals `1000`, I intend to increase the size by `100`. Once it reaches `1100`, increase it by `100` and so on.

Which do I choose out of `vector::resize()` and `vector::reserve()`? Is there any better choice in this kind of scenario?

**Edit**: I have sort of precise estimate for the `t_Names`. I estimate it to be around `700` to `800`. However in *certain* (seldom) situations, it can grow more than `1000`.

Comment: You realize that doing this means that vector growth is no longer _amortized constant time_ and you lose one of the performance benefits of using `std::vector`.

Comment: Related, see [C++ Made Easier: How Vectors Grow](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-made-easier-how-vectors-grow/184401375) on Dr. Dobbs site.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

The two functions do vastly different things!

The [`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) method (and passing argument to constructor is equivalent to that) will insert or delete appropriate number of elements to the vector to make it given size (it has optional second argument to specify their value). It will affect the `size()`, iteration will go over all those elements, push_back will insert after them and you can directly access them using the `operator[]`.

The [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) method only allocates memory, but leaves it uninitialized. It only affects `capacity()`, but `size()` will be unchanged. There is no value for the objects, because nothing is added to the vector. If you then insert the elements, no reallocation will happen, because it was done in advance, but that's the only effect.

So it depends on what you want. If you want an array of 1000 default items, use `resize()`. If you want an array to which you expect to insert 1000 items and want to avoid a couple of allocations, use `reserve()`.

**EDIT:** Blastfurnace's comment made me read the question again and realize, that in your case the correct answer is **don't preallocate** manually. Just keep inserting the elements at the end as you need. The vector will automatically reallocate as needed and will do it *more* efficiently than the manual way mentioned. The only case where `reserve()` makes sense is when you have reasonably precise estimate of the total size you'll need easily available in advance.

**EDIT2:** Ad question edit: If you have initial estimate, then `reserve()` that estimate. If it turns out to be not enough, just let the vector do it's thing.

Comment: I have edited the question. I do have certain estimate for the `vector`.

Comment: "The only case where reserve() makes sense is when you have reasonably precise estimate of the total size you'll need easily available in advance." - not strictly true, since calling `reserve()` yourself at specific times might sometimes help you manage any pointers or iterators that you have for elements of the vector (and in particular that they're invalidated by reallocation). Not that there's any sign in this question that such things are going on. And it's true that you need to know an upper bound on how many elements you'll add during the time your pointers/iterators are needed.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, right. Any code relying on that is somewhat fragile though, since if you make a mistake and don't allocate enough, you'll be up for very hard debugging session.

Comment: @Jan: well, it's fragile or not according to how difficult you've made it for yourself to maintain the required property. Something like `x.reserve(x.size() + newdata); vector<int>::iterator special_element = get_special_element(x); for (int i = 0; i < newdata; ++i) { if some_function(i, special_element) x.push_back(i); }` is pretty robust as far as reserving the space is concerned. I've no idea how many elements will actually be added, but I have an upper bound. Of course when in doubt, with vectors you can just use indexes instead of iterators, the difference is usually negligible.

Comment: Your wording makes sense to someone already aware of the correct answer, but could easily mislead people needing to ask the question.  "resize()...will insert given number of elements to the vector" - only true the first time it's used - it generally inserts the difference between the requested number and the pre-existing `size()`.  "The reserve() method only allocates memory" - it may or may not allocate memory depending on whether `capacity()` is already sufficient, it may also need to move elements and deallocate their original memory.  "want to avoid a couple of allocations" and copies etc

Comment: Actually, reserving before pushing is vital and must be used. Assume that you are coding some kind of 3d model loader and the model has like 15000 vertices. If you try to push_back each vertex while loading without pre-allocating them first, it will take serious time. I personally experienced that, I tried to load a car .obj model with near 100000 vertices, It took 30 seconds. Then I refactored the code using pre-allocation with .reserve(), now it takes 3 seconds. Just putting a .reserve(100000) in the beginning of the code saved 27 seconds.

Comment: "will insert given number of elements to the vector" makes it sound like the primary argument of the function is the number of elements to add, not the desired size of the vector.

Comment: To spell this out a bit more, think of the consequences of calling `push_back(element)` on your vector after calling `reserve()` or `resize()`. In  case you `resize()`d the vector, the effect is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @deniz That's trivial true at 100000 scale, but very not true at the 100-300 scale, where reserving can be wasteful if done unnecessarily.

Comment: @deniz Actually, when storing something like vertices, and you know how many will come, then `resize()` and assign by using `operator[]` or a walking pointer. Saves even more time. Also don't over-use `reserve`. One should at least be very wary not to cripple `push_back` performance by reserving in small increments. E.g. something like `vec.reserve(vec.size() + 1)`, to make sure that the following `push_back` won't throw, is poison for performance.

Comment: @PaulGroke You might be right for sufficiently basic types, but the statement is hard to rate without a scenario/benchmark. Also: Why would `push_back()` "throw" if the current `capacity` wasn't sufficient for a new element? How would `reserve()` solve that? It seems to me that if your `vector` is going to throw, it's because it can't allocate any more memory, so `reserve()` will fail just as much. And even without throwing, such a `reserve()` seems pointless because the `push_back()` (or `insert` or `emplace` etc.) would do it anyway.

Comment: @underscore_d The point is that after you have successfully `reserve()`d, you're guaranteed that `push_back` will not throw (assuming the ctor of the element doesn't throw). That means you can move the point of failure to some earlier point in time. Which is often required or at least very convenient when trying to keep invariants.

Comment: @underscore_d, the allocation that `push_back` may call may fail with `std::bad_alloc` exception. Very rare and completely fatal for most software, but there are cases where one might actually care.

Answer (score 47):

`resize()` not only allocates memory, it also *creates* as many instances as the *desired* size which you pass to `resize()` as argument. But `reserve()` only allocates memory, it doesn't create instances. That is,

```
std::vector<int> v1;
v1.resize(1000); //allocation + instance creation
cout <<(v1.size() == 1000)<< endl;   //prints 1
cout <<(v1.capacity()==1000)<< endl; //prints 1

std::vector<int> v2;
v2.reserve(1000); //only allocation
cout <<(v2.size() == 1000)<< endl;   //prints 0
cout <<(v2.capacity()==1000)<< endl; //prints 1
```

Output ([online demo](http://www.ideone.com/PQfRp)):

```
1
1
0
1
```

So `resize()` may not be desirable, if you don't want the default-created objects. It will be slow as well. Besides, if you `push_back()` new elements to it, the `size()` of the vector will further increase *by allocating new memory* (which also means moving the existing elements to the newly allocated memory space). If you have used `reserve()` at the start to ensure there is already enough allocated memory, the `size()` of the vector will increase when you `push_back()` to it, **but it will not allocate new memory again until it runs out of the space you reserved for it**.

Comment: After doing `reserve(N)`, we can use `operator []` harmlessly. correct ?

Comment: While most implementations will allocate the exact amount you request by `reserve`, the specification only requires it allocates at least that much, so some implementations may round up to some boundary and thus show higher capacity than 1000.

Comment: @iammilind: No, if the index is greater or equal to `v.size()`. Note that `reserve(N)` doesn't change `size()` of vector.

Comment: @iammilind: INcorrect. After calling reSERVE, no entries are added, only enough memory for adding them is obtained.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it looks like that you want to "reserve" the allocated storage space of vector t_Names.

Take note that `resize` initialize the newly allocated vector where `reserve` just allocates but does not construct. Hence, 'reserve' is **much faster** than 'resize'

You can refer to the documentation regarding the difference of [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) and [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/)

Comment: Please refer here instead: [vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) and [capacity](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html#3) _([why?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com]))_

Comment: Thanks for the addition of link, sehe

Answer (score 2):

reserve when you do not want the objects to be initialized when reserved. also, you may prefer to logically differentiate and track its count versus its use count when you resize. so there is a behavioral difference in the interface - the vector will represent the same number of elements when reserved, and will be 100 elements larger when resized in your scenario.

> Is there any better choice in this kind of scenario?

it depends entirely on your aims when fighting the default behavior. some people will favor customized allocators -- but we really need a better idea of what it is you are attempting to solve in your program to advise you well.

fwiw, many vector implementations will simply double the allocated element count when they must grow - are you trying to minimize peak allocation sizes or are you trying to reserve enough space for some lock free program or something else?

Comment: "_reserve when you do not want the objects to be initialized when reserved._" The correct formulation is when you do not want the objects to **exist**. It's not like an uninitialised array of a trivially constructible type, where the objects can't be read but could be assigned to; rather, only memory is reserved, but no objects exist in it, so they can't be accessed using `operator[]` or anything.