# When should we use reserve() of vector?

Tags: vector, stdvector

I always use resize() because I cannot use reserve as it gives error: vector subscript out of range. As I've read info about the differences of resize() and reserve(), I saw things like reserve() sets max. number of elements could be allocated but resize() is currently what we have. In my code I know max. number of elements but reserve() doesn't give me anything useful. So, how can I make use of reserve()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A vector has a *capacity* (as returned by `capacity()` and a *size* (as returned by `size()`. The first states how many elements a vector **can** hold, the second how many he **does currently** hold.

`resize` changes the size, `reserve` only changes the `capacity`.

See also the [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/resize/) and [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) documentation.

As for the use cases:
Let's say you know beforehand how many elements you want to put into your `vector`, but you don't want to initialize them - that's the use case for reserve. Let's say your vector was empty before; then, directly after `reserve()`, before doing any `insert` or `push_back`, you can, of course, not directly access as many elements as you reserved space for - that would trigger the mentioned error (subscript out of range) - since the elements you are trying to access are not yet initialized; the `size` is still 0. So the vector is still empty; but if you choose the reserved capacity in such a way that it's higher or equal to the maximum size your vector will get, you are avoiding expensive reallocations; and at the same time you will also avoid the (in some cases expensive) initialization of each vector element that resize would do.

With `resize`, on the other hand, you say: Make the vector hold as many elements as I gave as an argument; initialize those whose indices are exceeding the old size, or remove the ones exceeding the given new size.

Note that `reserve` will **never affect the elements currently in the vector** (except their storage location if reallocation is needed - but not their values or their number)! Meaning that if the size of a vector is currently greater than what you pass to a call to the reserve function on that same vector, reserve will just do nothing.

See also the answer to this question: [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Comment: I know beforhand how many elements I want to put into vector but what is the usage of that if I would not manipulate members of vector?

Comment: what do you mean by "if I would not manipulate members of vector"? With reserve, you need to `insert` or `push_back` (just as if you had not "reserve"d) but you will avoid reallocation, and you will also avoid the extra initialization that `resize` would trigger.... is it clear now?

Comment: With manipulation I mean e.g. vec[0]=0, vec[1]=1... If I use resize() would not I avoid reallocation also?

Comment: yes, but you would also initialize; and possibly remove elements if what you pass to resize is smaller then the vector's current size! Please read my answer and the documentationcarefully, it's all in there

Comment: But anyway I would initialize the vector otherwise what is the point of creating it? If I use reserve its like, "this is your capacity and just stay here without doing anything".

Comment: you can still call insert or push_back, which will basically copy the values of the elements into the vector. just because you can't see a sense in not initializing the elements doesn't mean that there aren't cases where it makes sense

Comment: I think I got it know. But to be sure, if I use reserve() and then use pushback(), because allocation already done, pushback() would not spend time to allocate memory. Am I right?

Comment: yes. anything I can add in my answer to make that more clear :D?

Answer (score 3):

**reserve()** is a **performance optimization** for using std::vector.

A typical std::vector implementation would reserve some memory on the first push_back(), for example 4 elements. When the 5th element gets pushed, the vector has to be resized: new memory has to be allocated (usually the size is doubled), the contents of the vector have to be copied to the new location, and the old memory has to be deleted.

This becomes an expensive operation when the vector holds a lot of elements. For example when you push_back() the 2^24+1th element, 16Million elements get copied just to add one element.

If you know the number of elements in advance you can `reserve()` the number of elements you are planning to `push_back()`. In this case expensive copy operations are not necessary because the memory is already reserved for the amount needed.

**resize()** in contrast **changes the number of elements** in the vector.

If no elements are added and you use `resize(20)`, 20 elements will now be accessable. Also the amount of memory allocated will increase to an implementation-dependent value.
If 50 elements are added and you use `resize(20)`, the last 30 elements will be removed from the vector and not be accessable any more. This doesn't necessarily change the memory allocated but this may also be implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

resize(n) allocates the memory for n objects and default-initializes them.

reserve() allocates the memory but does not initialize. Hence, reserve won't change the value returned by size(), but it will change the result of capacity().

Answer (score -2):

Edited after underscore_d's comment.

Description how functions implemented in VS2015

#### VS2015 CTP6

This error dialog exist only in the DEBUG mode, when `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2` is defined. In the RELEASE mode we don't have any problems. We get a current value by `return (*(this->_Myfirst() + _Pos)`, so `size` value isn't needed:

```
    reference operator[](size_type _Pos)
    {   // subscript mutable sequence
    #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (size() <= _Pos)
        {   // report error
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
        _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
        }

    #elif _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 1
    _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size());
    #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL */

    return (*(this->_Myfirst() + _Pos));
    }
```

If we see in the vector's source code, we can find, that a difference between `resize` and `reserve` is only in the changing of the value of `this->_Mylast()` in the func `resize()`.

`reserve()` calls `_Reallocate`.

`resize()` calls `_Reserve`, that calls `_Reallocate` and then `resize()` also changes the value of `this->_Mylast()`: `this->_Mylast() += _Newsize - size();` that is used in the `size` calculation(see last func)

```
    void resize(size_type _Newsize)
    {   // determine new length, padding as needed
    if (_Newsize < size())
        _Pop_back_n(size() - _Newsize);
    else if (size() < _Newsize)
        {   // pad as needed
        _Reserve(_Newsize - size());
        _TRY_BEGIN
        _Uninitialized_default_fill_n(this->_Mylast(), _Newsize - size(),
            this->_Getal());
        _CATCH_ALL
        _Tidy();
        _RERAISE;
        _CATCH_END
        this->_Mylast() += _Newsize - size();
        }
    }


    void reserve(size_type _Count)
    {   // determine new minimum length of allocated storage
    if (capacity() < _Count)
        {   // something to do, check and reallocate
        if (max_size() < _Count)
            _Xlen();
        _Reallocate(_Count);
        }
    }



    void _Reallocate(size_type _Count)
    {   // move to array of exactly _Count elements
    pointer _Ptr = this->_Getal().allocate(_Count);

    _TRY_BEGIN
    _Umove(this->_Myfirst(), this->_Mylast(), _Ptr);
    _CATCH_ALL
    this->_Getal().deallocate(_Ptr, _Count);
    _RERAISE;
    _CATCH_END

    size_type _Size = size();
    if (this->_Myfirst() != pointer())
        {   // destroy and deallocate old array
        _Destroy(this->_Myfirst(), this->_Mylast());
        this->_Getal().deallocate(this->_Myfirst(),
            this->_Myend() - this->_Myfirst());
        }

    this->_Orphan_all();
    this->_Myend() = _Ptr + _Count;
    this->_Mylast() = _Ptr + _Size;
    this->_Myfirst() = _Ptr;
    }

    void _Reserve(size_type _Count)
    {   // ensure room for _Count new elements, grow exponentially
    if (_Unused_capacity() < _Count)
        {   // need more room, try to get it
        if (max_size() - size() < _Count)
            _Xlen();
        _Reallocate(_Grow_to(size() + _Count));
        }
    }

    size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return length of sequence
    return (this->_Mylast() - this->_Myfirst());
    }
```

#### Problems

But some problems exist with `reserve`:

1. `end()` will be equal to `begin()`

**23.2.1 General container requirements**

**5:**

`end()` returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value for the container.

```
    iterator end() _NOEXCEPT
    {   // return iterator for end of mutable sequence
    return (iterator(this->_Mylast(), &this->_Get_data()));
    }
```

i.e. `_Mylast()` will be equal `_Myfirst()`

2. at() will generate an out_of_range exception.

**23.2.3 Sequence containers**

**17:**

The member function at() provides bounds-checked access to container elements. at() throws out_of_range if n >= a.size().

3. in the VisualStudio debugger we can see vector values, when size isn't 0

with `resize`:

[image]

with `reserve` and manually setted `#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0`:

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for UB. `resize` default-constructs any new elements and allows their indices to be accessed. `reserve` does not initialise the new capacity, and any attempts to access the newly allocated element-placeholders without having `emplace`d, `push`ed, or `resize`d into them is UB. The fact that the strict `.at()` does not allow this ought to imply to you that `operator[]` is not valid either. Giving a meandering account of what _currently happens to_ happen on one implementation is not useful and likely only to mislead readers,

Comment: "If the container size is greater than [index] n, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined." - http://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]