# Create new empty field in vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

So I have a vector, that is initally empty, but is surelly gone get filled. It contains instances of structure:

```
struct some {
    int number;
    MyClass classInstance;
}

/*Meanwhile later in the code:*/
vector<some> my_list;
```

When it happens, the I want to add value to vector, I need to enlarge it by one. But of course, I don't want to create any variables to do it. Without this requested, I'd do this:

```
//Adding new value:
some new_item;       //Declaring new variable - stupid, ain't it?
my_list.push_back(new_item); //Copying the variable to vector, now I have it twice!
```

So, instead, I want to create the `new_item` within the vector by increasing its size - have a look:

```
int index = my_list.size();
my_list.reserve(index+1);  //increase the size to current size+1 - that means increase by 1
my_list[index].number = 3;  //If the size was increased, index now contains offset of last item
```

But this does not work! It seems that space is not allocated - and I get **vector subscript out of range** error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my_list.reserve(index+1); // size() remains the same
```

Reserve doesn't change `my_list.size()`. It just increases the capacity. You are confusing this with `resize`:

```
my_list.resize(index+1);  // increase size by one
```

See also [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve) .

But I recommend another way:

```
my_vector.push_back(some());
```

The additional copy will be elided from your compiler, so there is no overhead. If you have C++11, you can do that more elegant by emplacing into the vector.

```
my_vector.emplace_back();
```

Comment: I'm very carefull when using `new`. Should I call both `.reserve` (to allocate) and `.resize` (to resize)?

Comment: Use reserve only if you insert many values into the vector. `resize` is very smart and increases the capacity by a constant factor (often 2) to provide a `push_back` in amortized constant time.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::reserve` only makes sure enough memory is allocated, it does not increase the size of the `vector`. You're looking for `std::vector::resize`.

Also, if you have a C++11 compiler, you can use `std::vector::emplace_back` to construct the new item in place, thus avoiding a copy.

```
my_list.emplace_back(42, ... ); // ... indicates args for MyClass constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

`reserve()` just *asks* the allocator for space, but does not actually fill it. Try `vector.resize()`