# Calling vector::reserve() on a vector reference

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have put together a theory that explains a phenomenon, but I'd like someone more knowledgeable to bear me up.

In the client code, I have:

```
vector<bool> candidates;
fillCandidates(candidates);
```

In the callee, I have:

```
void fillCandidates(vector<bool>& candidates)
{
    // reserve space for two elements
    candidates.reserve(2);
    candidates[0] = true;
    candidates[1] = false;
    // here, candidates.size() == 0
}
```

When I check the size of candidates after the return of the function, it is 0! What's happening? I'm using gcc 4.6.3 called in a CMake script on a Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (but I think all of this is actually irrelevant).

Note: I'm providing my interpretation as an answer.

**Edit:** The accepted answer and the comments beat me on timing, so my interpretation wouldn't add anything.

Comment: Either call `resize` instead of `reserve` as the answer mentions, or call `push_back` instead of `operator[]` after calling `reserve`.

Comment: FWIW, doing a `reserve` is more appropriate only when the count is high and is known beforehand. Calling `resize` and then overwriting elements is mostly less performant, except for PODs/built-ins. If you can use C++11, doing an `emplace_back` is apt in most cases and performant too.

Comment: @legends2k: Could you point me to the source of your statement about the performance of `emplace_back`? It's interesting.

Comment: @sturmer: [push_back vs emplace_back](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4303513/183120)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling resize, not reserve.

See the differences here: 
[Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Edit to answer comments below:

The short answer is yes, calling operator[] on a vector that is only reserved is an error, and anything could happen.

The long answer is read this article http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm

> v.reserve( 2 ); 
>   v[0] = 1; 
>   v[1] = 2; 
>   Both of the above lines are flat-out errors, but
>   they might be hard-to-find flat-out errors because they'll likely
>   "work" after a fashion on your implementation of the standard library.

I suggest reading the whole thing.
In your case I would use `push_back` instead of resizing manually. But I would benchmark performance if you are really concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But then, as a side question, am I doing anything evil by using `operator[]` to assign the values?

Comment: And anyway, I did not mean to assign 2 default values (which is what would have happened by using `resize()`). I really meant to reserve enough space, before assigning values. Isn't my real error trying to assign values with `operator[]`? Since in my case `size()` returns 0, using `operator[]` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @sturmer: if you're determined that you don't want your vector element to briefly take on a default value then you can create it with `push_back` instead of `resize()`. In the case of `bool` it's likely to be less efficient, though (not that efficiency is going to matter for two `bool`s). vector never has elements that haven't been initialized, and that's an intended feature.