# Sorting class members in a template class in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am pretty inexperienced in C++ and I have a very strange problem when sorting a vector which is of type "T" that is a class member/attribute in a template class. The program compiles and run but calling "sort" over that attribute does work properly: it is not ordered at all after calling. However, I can create a local vector of type T inside a method and get ir ordered properly. What am I doing wrong?

I also include a simple and fast example of this situation. This is the template class (TempClass.h):

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <class T> class TempClass{
    public:
        TempClass(T a, T b, T c){
            container.clear();
            container.reserve(3);
            container[0] = a; container[1] = b; container[2] = c;
        }

        void modifyAttribute(){
            printf("Previous state:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("[%d] -> %d\n", i, container[i].read());
            }
            sort(container.begin(), container.end(), std::greater<T>());
            printf("Final state:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("[%d] -> %d\n", i, container[i].read());
            }
        }

        void testLocally(){
            std::vector<T> localContainer(3);
            localContainer[0] = T(14); localContainer[1] = T(97); localContainer[2] = T(42);
            printf("Previous state:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("[%d] -> %d\n", i, localContainer[i].read());
            }
            sort(localContainer.begin(), localContainer.end(), std::greater<T>());
            printf("Final state:\n");
            for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
                printf("[%d] -> %d\n", i, localContainer[i].read());
            }
        }

    private:
        std::vector<T> container;
};
```

And a possible simple usage of it (Tester.cpp):

```
#include "TempClass.h"

class Value{
    public:
        Value(){
            this->val = 0;
        }

        Value(int val){
            this->val = val;
        }

        Value(const Value& reference){
            this-> val = reference.val;
        }

        bool operator >(const Value& other) const{
            printf("Ok...\n");
            return this->val > other.val;
        }

        int read(){
            return this->val;
        }

    private:
        int val;
};

int main(){
    TempClass<Value> object(Value(6), Value(17), Value(43));
    object.testLocally();
    object.modifyAttribute();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not really know what is happening :( Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: This is it: Previous state:
[0] -> 14
[1] -> 97
[2] -> 42
Ok...
Ok...
Ok...
Ok...
Final state:
[0] -> 97
[1] -> 42
[2] -> 14
Previous state:
[0] -> 6
[1] -> 17
[2] -> 43
Final state:
[0] -> 6
[1] -> 17
[2] -> 43

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you call `container.reserve(3);` you increase the capacity of the vector (size of the internal storage), but the vector remains empty. `operator[]` doesn't insert elements, so when you do this:

```
container.reserve(3);
container[0] = a; container[1] = b; container[2] = c;
```

You're accessing some elements that don't actually exist in the vector, the vector is still empty after this.

The method that does what you want is `resize()`, which actually increases the size of the vector.

The constructor that you call in your `testLocally` method sets the initial size of the vector, not it's initial capacity, that's why in that method it works as you expect it to work.

Comment: Mmm, well, thank you very much. I won't forget it! I had no idea about what was happening. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling `reserve` instead of `resize` and going out of bounds in your `TempClass` constructor here.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve) for more details on the two functions.

Other than that it seems to be working, unless the code you are using is different than what you posted here.

On a side note, `this->val` is unnecessary.  just use `val`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I can give just a green tick but I also voted up your answer. Regards