# Can I create a C++ string/vector with specified length but no initialization?

Tags: c++, string, vector, initialization

I need create a `string`/`vector`. I know how long it should be, however, I'd like to write the right thing into it later. Can I create it with a specified length but without any initialization (neither explicit nor implicit), like what malloc does? Because I'll write into it properly before reading from it, it would be a waste of time to initialize it at construction.

I hoped I could write with arbitrary order after creating the vector, like

```
vector<int> v(10); // Some magic to create v with 10 of uninitialized ints
v[6] = 1;
v[3] = 2;
...
```

Seemingly that's impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

Comment: can also use constructor with size_t.

Comment: @SHR, this will call the default constructor (if its implemented)

Comment: Could you use `std::array`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks for your answer and comment. I think `std::array` would be good in the example I gave. However I could not use it in the real cases I met because `string`/`vector` was specified by the interface. Also, in some of the cases the size would be determined at run time instead of compile time.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question properly, you want [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) or [`std::basic_string::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve).

```
std::vector<int> v;               // empty vector
v.reserve(how_long_it_should_be); // insure the capacity
v.push_back(the_right_thing);     // add elements
...
```

**Edit for question's edit**

`vector<int> v(10);`, will always construct `v` with 10 default-initialized `int`, i.e. `0`. You might want [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you could know the size at compile time.

```
std::array<int, 10> v;  // construct v with 10 uninitialized int
v[6] = 1;
v[3] = 2;
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/DAQOLF77457)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can, with [`boost::noinit_adaptor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/noinit_adaptor.html):

```
vector<int, boost::noinit_adaptor<std::allocator<int>> v(10);
```

Under the hood it redefines `allocator::construct` to do *default initialization* using `new(p) T` instead of *value initialization* `new(p) T()`.

For built-in types *default initialization* does nothing, whereas *value initialization* zero-initializes.

Comment: This is the only exact answer to the question as calling ``.reserve()`` means having calls to ``.push_back()`` in order, whereas the OP seems to require random access to the container after non-initialized allocation.

Answer (score 5):

Using `.reserve()` on either containers will increase the `.capacity()` of the internal memory block allocated without calling any default constructors.

You can assert that the container has the right capacity at the moment you need it using `.capacity()`. Note that `.size()` will be different to `.capacity()` after a `.reserve()` as the first returns the number of actual objects inside the container, while the seconds returns the total number of objects the current memory block can handle without reallocation.

It is good practice (especially for `std::vector`) to empirically `.reserve()` your containers to avoid extra allocations at runtime. If you are using at least C++11, in case you want the remaining memory back and you can deal with some copying/moving, you can use `shrink_to_fit()`.

Note that `std::string::reserve` differs from `std::vector::reserve` in case the new capacity requested is smaller than the current capacity. The string will take it as a non-binding request to shrink, while the vector will ignore the request.

Answer (score 1):

When growing a vector, the new object must be initialized one way or another. It's not possible to create a vector of uninitialized `int` objects, for example.

The closest you could get would be to define a class with a data member and a  default constructor that does not initialize that member, e.g.:

```
struct bar { int x; bar() {} };

// ...
std::vector<bar> vec(5);
```

Then `vec` ultimately contains 5 uninitialized `int` subobjects.

The `reserve` function allocates memory but does not increase the count of objects in the vector; it does not help with the problem that when you do eventually want an object in the vector you must initialize that object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.resize(x)` to change the actual number of elements.
* If `.size() > x` then elements will be destroyed, back first.
* If `.size() < x` new elements will be added using their default constructor.

Use `.reserve(x)` to have the vector allocate memory for x elements but not instantiate any (`.size()` will not change).
* If `.size() < x` no action will be taken, and the vector will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

From C++11 you can use fill constructor:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/
(2) fill constructor
    Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of val (if provided).
BTW: there is quite big difference between string and vector.

Comment: he wants to increase the capacity without initialization.

Comment: According to doc it is initialized if val is provided.
Are you sure it will be initialized?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted. OP wants to avoid initialization. He just wants to pre-allocate raw memory to avoid the cost of allocation when he adds data in his container.

Comment: @MarcinKajzler I think the default constructor will be called if val is not provided.

Comment: Initializing is not usually the expensive part of allocation.