# How to accept user input for the size of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have declared `std::vector<Training> _classes;` in `Training.h` as a private variable. I want to first get `_noOfClasses` from the user and then initialise the `vector` with that many elements, but I am getting an error:

> call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or
>   conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

```
Training::Training() : _noOfClasses(0) {
    std::cout << "Enter the number of class\n";
    std::cin >> _noOfClasses;
    _classes(_noOfClasses); //Error
}
```

How do I initialize the size of the `vector` from user input, separately?

Comment: Side note: don't use leading underscores when naming your own symbols: _" Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace."_ (C++ ISO standard, section 17.6.4.3.2).

Comment: @Michael member variables are not in the global namespace, so that's fine.

Comment: @Michael And it's not followed immediately by an uppercase letter, so would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reverse the order - unless the `Training` class is an "I/O" class, I would separate the construction of the `Training` class from any user input. Obtain the number of classes first and then construct the `Training` instance from the obtained user input.

```
std::size_t noOfClasses;
std::cout << "Enter the number of class\n";
std::cin >> noOfClasses;
// ...
Training::Training(std::size_t noOfClasses)
: classes_(noOfClasses), noOfClasses_(noOfClasses) {
}
```

That said, you can factor the I/O out into a function of its own and use the result as the argument (error checking omitted);

```
std::size_t GetTrainingSize()
{
    std::size_t i;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of class\n";
    std::cin >> i;
    return i;
}

Training::Training() : classes_(GetTrainingSize()) {
    // if needed...
    _noOfClasses = classes_.size();
}
```

To resize a `std::vector` after construction, the member `resize()` method can be used. The OP code would then look like;

```
Training::Training() : _noOfClasses(0) {
    std::cout << "Enter the number of class\n";
    std::cin >> _noOfClasses;
    _classes.resize(_noOfClasses);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`_classes(_noOfClasses);` is not valid syntax, `_classes` is not functor and you can't invoke function on it. You could use [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to resize it to contain `_noOfClasses` elements.

```
_classes.resize(_noOfClasses);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use _classes.reserve() or _classes.resize() depending on your need 
to know about them follow this link :[Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)