# Initializing a vector<T> using elements from a vector<SuperSetofT> (mapping function?)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class SomeType { int32_t variable; }

std::vector<SomeType> myVector(10);

// ... code to work with myVector

std::vector<int32_t> myOtherVector;
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    myOtherVector.push_back(myVector[i].variable);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I've seen how I can use a lambda to do complex initialization, but I can't figure out how to "map" (in C# terms) a Type's certain fields onto this new vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be initializing, but you can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
myOtherVector.resize(myVector.size());
std::transform(myVector.cbegin(), myVector.cend(), myOtherVector.begin(), 
               [](auto const& s){
    return s.variable;
});
```

or with [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
myOtherVector.reserve(myVector.size()); // optional
std::transform(myVector.cbegin(), myVector.cend(), std::back_inserter(myOtherVector),
               [](auto const& s){
    return s.variable;
});
```

You can *initialize* it with Boost's [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
auto tr = [](auto const& s){
    return s.variable;
});

vector<int32_t> myOtherVector(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myVector.begin(), tr),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(myVector.end(), tr)
);
```

Comment: very nice, I was just reading about transform, so good use case.

Comment: you also choose between reserve vs resize? What's up with that?

Comment: That's proably another question :) `reserve` just changes `vector`'s `capacity`. That is, its `size` does not change, but you can `push_back` without fear of reallocation (and invalidation of pointers, iterators and references) as long as `size` < `capacity`. On the other hand, `resize` changes the `size` of the vector, zero-initializing the elements if necessary. That's why the first version required a `resize` - because it depended on the size being no less than 10, while for the second it's just an optimization

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve

Comment: Thanks. I just realized though that I have to create two such smaller vectors, so while I like this, I'll be iterating twice if I use it, so I'll be using the loop instead :(

Comment: Wow, `make_transform_iterator` is _incredibly_ useful!

Answer (score 0):

I little better (IMHO)

```
for ( auto const &  elem : myVector )
{
    myOtherVector.emplace_back(elem.variable);
}
```