# C++ vector subscript out of range, no logic error, cannot figure out

Tags: c++, vector

When I run this code it gives me a debug assertion failed, line 1232, vector subscript out of range.

```
Maze::Maze(bool verbose = false)
// verbose == true means an intro and prompts for input will be printed
{
  int i, j, dimension;

  if (verbose) {
    cout << "Welcome to the Rat in the Maze program, where we will find a\n"
     << "path from the start cell to the end cell of a maze so that Remy\n"
     << "may escape.  You will first enter the data specifying the maze.\n"
     << "After that, if escape is possible, we will show an escape path\n"

         << "Enter the number of rows and columns of the maze: " << endl;
  }   
  cin >> dimension;
  size = dimension+2; // add the hedge rows and columns
  if (verbose)
    cout << "Enter the row and column indices of the start: " << endl;
  cin >> start;
  if (verbose)
    cout << "Enter the row and column indices of the exit: " << endl;
  cin >> exitpos;


/Here is where I got the error:/
  M.reserve(size);
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    M[i].reserve(size);
    for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
      M[i][j] = WALL;
  }

  if(verbose) {
    cout << "For each row, enter the column indices of the open squares\n";
    cout << "Terminate the row input with a non-positive value" << endl;
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= size-2; i++) {
    if (verbose)
      cout << "Row " << i << ": ";  
    cin >> j;
    assert(j < 1 || 1 <= j && j <= size-2);

    while (j > 0){
      M[i][j] = OPEN;
      cin >> j;
      assert(j < 1 || 1 <= j && j <= size-2);
    };
  }

  if (!(M[start.row][start.col] == OPEN)) 
    M[start.row][start.col] = OPEN;
}
```

M is an object of stateTable, which defined as below:

```
typedef vector<vector<state> > stateTable;
```

There is no logic error in the code but I got this error, and one thing I know is our instructor wrote and compile this code under Linux environment while I'm doing that under VC environment. Is that the reason?

Comment: Copy the source as text, not as images. Also, [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please take a few minutes to read [ask].

Comment: Post the code here.

Comment: M.reserve(size);
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    M[i].reserve(size);
    for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
      M[i][j] = WALL;
  }

Comment: edit your question please.

Comment: typedef vector<vector<state> > stateTable;

Comment: first time using Stack Overflow, let me just re-ask the question.

Comment: Just [edit] it...

Comment: Okay, the code has been posted.

Comment: How do you know there isn't a logic error? That's a bold thing to claim, especially given the error. An out of range error pretty much ensures you have a logic error somewhere.

Comment: Please, note that [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) doesn't do what you seem to think.

Comment: This code is not written by me, it was given by my professor and I'm trying to figure out why it gives me error.

Comment: The code is trying to build a 2D array to store the information of a maze.

Comment: The primary object of Stack Overflow is not to read documentation for you. You're going to have to do this yourself: [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Answer (score 4):

The method `reserve` does not creates new elements of a vector. It just reserve memory for future elements. So you may not use the subscript operator to access non-existent elements.

Instead of the method `reserve` use method `resize` if you want to create new elements.

For example

```
  M.resize(size);
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    M[i].resize(size);
    for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
      M[i][j] = WALL;
  }
```

Or just write

```
M.resize(n, std::vector<state>( size, WALL) );
```

Comment: Wow, really helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
 M.reserve(size);
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     M[i].reserve(size);
     for (j = 0; j < size; ++j)
         M[i][j] = WALL;
 }
```

The reason is that a vector's `reserve()` method does not set up the elements for use.    Using them in this way gives undefined behaviour on accessing `M[i]` and `M[i][j]`.

Change the calls of `M.reserve(size)` and `M[i].reserve(size)` to use `resize()` (i.e. to use `M.resize(size)` and `M[i].resize(size)` instead.

The difference is that `resize()` also ensures the elements are ready for use (among other things).

The difference reflects the purpose of `resize()` as being to set the number of elements available for use, whereas `reserve()` is concerned with controlling how often `resize()` - and other operations that resize the container - actually reallocate memory.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7397862/1640610) elaborates on Peter's explanation of the difference between `resize()` and `reserve()`.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I need more understanding.