# Code out of range. How can this vector be allocated dynamically?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm fairly new to c++ and started writing a small poker game to help me get some more experience with vectors. I'm getting a runtime error in the second function, which is really no surprise after reading the post below and discovering I was misunderstanding the behavior of the reserve() class member.  I believe I could probably remedy this with resize() but I was hoping for some creative input on a way that I could re-construct this function to allocate dynamically.  The difficulty I'm having with the dynamic allocation is that I am trying to make the deal function distribute cards to each player as in a real card game (yes I realize that this is somewhat statistically superfluous).  I could do this with pointer math in c fairly easily, and I think I could fix this by statically allocating some of these vectors, but I would prefer to utilize c++ as elegant and efficient as possible.  Any suggestions on a way to do this dynamically? That is, how can I completely avoid allocating or reserving space for the containers used in the `deal()` function?

[Choice between vector::resize() and vector::reserve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

const int __handSize__ = 5;

class Hand {
public:
    std::vector<int> held;
    std::vector<int> played;
};

std::vector<int> shuffle() {
    std::vector<int> deck;
    for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ){
        deck.push_back( i );
    }
    std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
    assert( 52 == deck.size() );
    return deck;
}

std::vector<Hand> deal( int nPlayers, std::vector<int> &deck ) {
    std::vector<Hand> playerHands;
    playerHands.reserve( nPlayers );
    for( int i = 0; i > __handSize__; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < nPlayers; j++ ) {
            playerHands.at(j).held.push_back( deck.back() );
        }
    }
    return playerHands;
}

int main() {
    srand(time( NULL ));
    std::vector<int> deck = shuffle();
    std::vector<Hand> hand = deal( 3, deck );
    std::cout << hand.at(1).held.at(1) <<std::endl;

}
```

output:

```
dmf86@tux3:~/src/poker$ ./poker
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted
```

Back trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff74aa428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
#1  0x00007ffff74ac02a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7ae484d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7ae26b6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7ae2701 in std::terminate() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7ae2919 in __cxa_throw ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7b0b3f7 in std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x000000000040218c in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const ()
#8  0x0000000000401785 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::at(unsigned long) ()
#9  0x0000000000401030 in main ()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: See above, adding more output information

Comment: Look at the size of `hand` after the call to `deal`

Comment: Yeah, zero.  Strangely enough, it exhibits the same behavior whether I use resize or reserve.

Comment: Try tracing through your loops in `deal` and see how many cards are actually added.

Comment: I don't believe any are being added since the parent vector has a size of 0

Comment: Reserve is wrong in any case. at(j) does not exist when it has no size. You need to use resize anyway. If it doesn't work with this, then it might be because of your Hand class. May I ask why Hand has no constructor? Also, why do you use functions instead of methods of some class like Game?

Comment: I'd rather use deque and add\remove cards\nodes from\to it. Same with deck. To avoid constant reallocation of memory.

Comment: I will be turning both of these functions into methods once they work. Trying to keep it simple til I fix the problem.

Comment: You need the `resize` and you have another problem. The outer for loop condition `i > __handSize__` is wrong, it should be `i < __handSize__`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__hand_size__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @Blastfurnace good catch

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah I knew someone would point that out. Hopefully nobody adds a poker class to STL :)

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a typo. I think you should have caught the bad comparison if you stepped through your code in a debugger.

Comment: @mreff555 -- to be clear, if the standards committee added a `poker` class to the standard library, it would be in namespace `std` and **would not** conflict with your code, unless you do something silly like `using namespace std;`. The problem with `__hand_size__` is that its reserved for **any** use, which allows it to be in the global namespace, and allows it to be a macro. Either way, code that tries to define that name is in trouble.

Comment: Yes I knew that and did it anyway. Ive already changed it. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Azuith,  Just out of curiosity, why do I need an explicit constructor for hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my own question and thought I should share.  Thanks to swift Aziuth for their input.  Its far from done, or even functional, but this will work well. I decided that it would be useful to keep track of whether a player had folded and therefore no longer active, so I added a boolean member "active" to the Hand class. This has the added benefit of allowing me to force the Deck::deck vector to initialize empty structures without having to manually resize them.

I also broke it up into three classes to keep each one small and simple.

```
class Hand {
public:
    std::vector<int> held;
    std::vector<int> played;
    bool active;
};

class Deck {
    const int _handSize_ = 5;
    std::vector<int> deck;
public:
    void shuffle();
    int getCard();
};

class Players {
    std::vector<Hand> playerNo;
    int activePlayers;
public:
    Players( int n );
    void addCard( int player, Deck &deck );
    bool isActive( int n );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the aversion to reserving or resizing vectors?  When I know the size that a vector needs to be, I always reserve or resize it.  That choice depends upon how I intend to fill it.

Especially for large vectors, reserving the size to the proper value is a better practice than allowing it to keep resizing as it grows (which it must do).

I see no reason to not reserve or resize the deck to 52, and the hands to 5, since that is what they will have to grow to as they are used.

If you are going to use push_back to fill the vectors, reserve them.  If you are going to use assignment, resize it.

e.g.

```
vector<int> deck;  // create empty vector
deck.resize(52);   // resize to 52 elements
// now size = 52, and capacity = 52

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    deck[i] = i;   // assign the elements
```

or:

```
vector<int> deck(52);  // create vector with 52 elements
// size = 52 and capacity = 52

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    deck[i] = i;    // assign to the elements
```

or:

```
vector<int> deck;
deck.reserve(52);    // reserve space for 52 elements
// size = 0, capacity = 52

for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    deck.push_back(i);  // push to create the elements
// now size = 52, capacity = 52
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectors do not re-allocate whenever you add or remove an element. The allocated size can differ from the size used - as you have already noticed with the difference between `reserve()` and `resize()`. As the vector size increases, the allocations become larger, so that the amount of allocated "slack" is a constant factor (IIANM) times the length of the vector. Thus, for n insertions, you only make O(log(n)) re-allocation calls. Similarly, when you remove elements, space is de-allocated only when the ratio of size to reserved size drops below some point - if at all.

**Edit:** Following the clarification - about not wanting to have to do *any* resizing or reserving - a possible option could be using a map instead of a vector. `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` have an `operator[]` with an "insert if missing, update otherwise" semantic. In fact, I'll also add some more changes, and propose a "deal" function:

```
auto deal(const SomeKindOfContainer& players, std::vector<Card>& deck) {
    std::unordered_map<Player, Hand> playerHands;
    auto handSize = deck.size() / players.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < hand_size; i++) {
        for(const auto& player : Players) {
            playerHands[player].held.push_back( deck.pop_back() );
        }
    }
    return playerHands;
}
```

The nice thing here is that it doesn't assume the players are integers; and,  in fact, maybe you're going to use strings instead. The players could be, say, a `std::vector`, or an `std::unordered_set`.

Also, using maps or sets is "wasteful", as these use pointers and perform many allocations; so if you were working on millions of players and cards, I would have suggested something else. but in your example efficiency is not really a concern.

<sub>PS - As @PeterBecker mentions, the C++ standard only requires amortized constant-time insertion, rather than everything I've described - which is a description of what library implementations typically have.</sub>

Comment: Concerning your "PS"; that expansion behavior is required by the standard: Insertions at the end are required to be "amortized constant time", which is implemented by the scheme that you describe. Removing elements does not have time-complexity requirements, and most implementations don't shrink the allocated space.

Comment: I agree, that's actually why I posted this. I would prefer to use vectors as they were intended and not preallocate.

Comment: @mreff555: So - does this answer your question? Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: Not really no. It's great information but it's pretty much exactly what I learned before posting this.  I was hoping to eliminating resize or reserve entirely.

Comment: @mreff555: Then why don't you say that outright in the question? :-(

Comment: Read the last sentence.

Comment: @einpoklum look. You gave some solid information I gave you one up for it but no you did not answer my question.

Comment: @mreff555: Have updated my answer to address your actual question.