# Load data into std::vector<char> efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, stdvector, ifstream

My understanding is that you can access the data in a std::vector using pointers. For example:

```
char *ptr;
std::vector<char> v1 {'A', 'B', 'C'};
ptr = &v1[0]
if (*(ptr+1) == 'B')
    std::cout << "Addressing via pointer works\n";
```

How about loading a std::vector directly? For example:

```
std::vector<char> v2;
v2.reserve(3); // allocate memory in the vector 
ptr = &v2[0]
*ptr = 'A';
*(ptr+1) = 'B';
*(ptr+2) = 'C';
if (v2[1] == 'B')
    std::cout << "Data is in vector buffer!\n";
```

but

```
if (!v2.size())
    std::cout << "But the vector doesn't know about it!\n";
```

My question: Is there any way to tell the v2 vector that its internal memory buffer is loaded with data? This would be useful when you want to use a std::vector to hold data that is sourced from a file stream.

I look forward to your comments.

Comment: `reserve` doesn't change size, only capacity. For the rest of the code to be valid replace `reserve` with `resize`.

Comment: What you are doing is modify memory owned by the vector without telling it what you have done.

Comment: why do you think that accessing the vector via the pointer `ptr` is more efficient?

Comment: Assigning to memory outside of the `vector`'s size, like you're doing here, is undefined behavior. For specific implementations you can verify whether it's fine or not (it *probably* is but that's no guarantee that the compiler or stdlib version next year will be fine). And then there's the issue that increasing the size of the `std::vector` will default initialize the elements, so you'll have to go back and reset them to the value you want. Either make the vector using the sized constructor `std::vector<char> v2(3)` and then assign, or use list initialization.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397768/choice-between-vectorresize-and-vectorreserve

Comment: See example how to load a file into a vector: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator

Comment: To do something like you want with a lazy resizing you'd have to specify a custom "lazy" allocator so that the elements aren't default initialized. But still, just use list initialization. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

Comment: @bolov The reason for accessing the vector via a pointer is that some lower level file i/o functions require a pointer to a buffer. (e.g. ifsteam::read) Now, I have to read the file into an allocated char buffer, and then copy it to the vector.

Comment: @Mansoor Exactly. My question is - Since it is possible to resize the vector, is it also possible to modify the vectors memory and have the vector recognize that inserted data?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Good point about the default initialization when a vector is resized. Unfortunately, the std::vector<char> is a private class member that is used post creation so the sized constructor or list initialization doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell the v2 vector that its internal memory buffer is loaded with data?

No.

The behaviour of your second example is undefined.

> This would be useful when you want to use a std::vector to hold data that is sourced from a file stream.

You can read a file into vector like this:

```
std::vector<char> v3(count);
ifs.read(v3.data(), count);
```

Or like this:

```
using It = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
std::vector<char> v4(It{ifs}, It{});
```

Comment: Thanks for your examples. In my case, the std::vector<char> is already created as a buffer in the class's private space. Both of the examples above make use of the std::vector constructor. How would you load an already existing std::vector<char> with the ifs stream?

Comment: What I am doing now is loading the file content into a char buffer[] sized by the stream buffer size into, and then copying it into the existing vector.