# How can I take input from user and store it in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, input, visual-studio-2019

Unable to take input from user and store it in a vector. How to do that?
Just started learning to code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
int total_even = 0;
int product_odd = 1;
std::vector<int>numbers;
std::cout << "Enter 6 digits: ";
std::cin >> numbers;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

    if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {

        total_even = total_even + numbers[i];
    }
    else {
        product_odd = product_odd * numbers[i];
    }
}
std::cout << "Sum of numbers is: " << total_even << "\n";
std::cout << "Product of odd numbers is: " << product_odd << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: A vector in the begining has size 0 - the for loop will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you take inputs in a vector:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
for(int i = 0; i < /*6 in your case*/; i++) {
    int temp;
    if(scanf("%d",&temp)) {
        numbers.push_back(temp);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "something wrong with vector" << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Another way would be using a for-each loop. But, you need to know the size before hand in this case:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(size);
for(auto& elem : numbers) {
    std::cin >> elem;
}
```

For more information, take a look at [How does c++ std::vector work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167272/how-does-c-stdvector-work/3167372)

Comment: you can also check using *cin*, `if (std::cin >> temp) numbers.push_back(temp); else { ... }`, note to be able to read again int it is needed to clear the flag and to bypass the non valid int, like `std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: I put an answer for a similar case in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56585205/2458991