# How do I get char * from vector<char>?

Tags: c++

I have declared a vector like this

```
vector<char> vbuffer;
```

and used it as a receive buffer like this..

```
recv = read(m_fd, &m_vbuffer[totalRecv], SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
```

It seems like working and now I want to get the raw char data for parsing..

If I have defined a function like this..

```
char* getData(){
//return char data from the vector

}
```

How would I fill inside of the function? Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you think `&m_vbuffer[totalRecv]` is doing?  Have you resized the vector first?

Comment: That third argument needs to be `m_vbuffer.size() - totalRecv`.  If you don't subtract the current offset, you can overrun the buffer.

Comment: Here you go - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1339470/57428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't resize the vector in any way, you can use `&vbuffer[0]` as a pointer to the array. There are many operations that will invalidate pointers to a vector though, make sure you don't call any of them while you have a pointer in use.

Answer (score 4):

in c++0x, simply do `m_vbuffer.data()`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a pointer to the first element in the vector, so you can use it like an array:

```
&m_vbuffer[0]
```