# GetAdapterAddresses function with NEW instead of MALLOC

Tags: c++, network-programming, winsock

I would use the `GetAdaptersAddresses()` function of windows to get some informations about the adapters of the computer. In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) MSDN page there is a big example of how to use it. But I'm using C++ so I would stick with the `new` keyword and not `malloc` (C native). How can I rewrite the parts that uses `malloc` with `new`?

**EDIT 1**

```
std::vector<PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES> buffer;
ULONG outBufferLen = 0;

if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, NULL, &outBufferLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
{
    buffer.resize(outBufferLen);

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES addresses = reinterpret_cast<PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES>(buffer.data());

    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, addresses, &outBufferLen) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        for (; addresses != NULL; addresses = addresses->Next)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
ULONG outBufferLen = 0;

if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, NULL, &outBufferLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES p = new IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[outBufferLen / sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)];

    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX, NULL, p, &outBufferLen) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The easier solution is to use a `std::vector<char>`, and resize that.

Comment: @MSalters could I do something like what I wrote in the EDIT 2?

Comment: Well, that rounds down instead of up. Unless `outBufferLen` is a mulitple of `sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)`, you've got a buffer overflow. Also, please note that you won't actually get a `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES[]` from `GetAdaptersAddresses`.

Comment: @MSalters ok so, could you please make me an example of how should I implement vector to get the code working?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly rewrite that code using `new`/`delete`, because introducing `new` would induce risk of exceptions and that code is not exceptions safe. A dumb way would be to call `::operator new( size_t, const nothrow_t&)` instead of `malloc()` - but this is really ugly.

The real solution is to rewrite all code using proper C++ classes. `std::vector` would be a good fit for `pAddresses` and you'd need a RAII wrapper for `lpMsgBuf`.

Comment: Using `nothrow new` is ugly enough to not be recommended IMHO.

Comment: @Als: That often happens to dumb decisions.

Comment: @sharptooth I'm missing what is a RAII wrapper. Can you explain me?

Comment: @sharptooth Ok, but how can I use a function that accepts raw pointers with std::vector?

Comment: @Stefano: Just resize the vector to hold enough data and get a raw pointer to its first element - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1339470/57428

Comment: @sharptooth using vectors means that I cannot eventually use iterators to cycle throught all the adapters, is this right?

Comment: @Stefano: I see no reason why you can't use iterators.

Comment: @sharptooth I've edited my question with the actual code that I have. GetAdaptersAddresses returns a linked list, using vectors means that with that code I will create a vector of outBufferLen elements.